# Confusing phasor representation

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor, capacitance, inductance

Why capacitive impedance has the magnitude \$Z_{c} = \frac{-j}{\omega C}\$ but in the phasor diagram, we represent it as a vector pointing in the upward direction?. Same is with the case of an inductor, do we have a concrete proof on this?

Comment: The capacitor vector should point in down direction not upward.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389071/rl-c-circuit-problem/389088#389088

Comment: `-j` is downwards by convention. What are your sources?

Comment: Isn't it that in the Argand plane **-j** is in the negative direction?

Comment: `-` is negative, yes.

Comment: So why not \$X_{c}\$ points in negative direction?

Comment: I asked for your sources. It should point to the negative direction.

Comment: \$V(t) = V_{m}sin(\omega t)\$ is the voltage source I've used.

Comment: "sources" like in "source of information"

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What sources of information?

Comment: Where do you read that \$\frac{-j}{\omega C}\$ is represented by an upwards arrow?

Comment: _Understanding Physics: Electricity and Magnetism by DC Pandey_

Comment: We need the exact citation. Otherwise the answer "no, it is not."

Comment: Xc is a scalar, not a vector quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only imagine either you or the person who draw that phasor diagram are confused by complex math.

$$Z_L = jωL$$
$$Z_C = \frac{1}{jωC} = \frac{-j}{ωC}$$

The \$-j\$ comes from the fact \$1/j = -j\$. And that's an arrow pointing in just the opposite direction of the inductor one.
[image]

Comment: What's the direction of \$Z_{c}\$? upward or downward?

Comment: @SahilSilare He said "just the opposite direction of the inductor one".

Comment: -j points in the negative j direction. Downwards. 1/j does the same, because it is the same. It's just not that visible. This often leads to confusion. You aren't the first one. The person who drew that picture either.

Comment: @KingDuken That's a circular definition...

Comment: Means there is no specified direction of \$Z_{C}\$ and \$Z_{L}\$ ?

Comment: @Janka But in the phasor we represent \$Z_{C}\$ towards upward direction even when the "-" sign is multiplied. Why?

Comment: There is a specified direction. ← -1 , 0, +1 → and the same for ↑+j, 0, -j↓

Comment: @SahilSilare do you want to share with us the picture you are referring to? You were told like 5 times right now, that by convention it is *downwards* and not *upwards*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm finding a reason for that convention.

Comment: @Janka Perhaps a demonstration of the real and imaginary plane would help the OP understand?

Comment: I afraid we have some kind of communication barrier here.

Comment: @KingDuken Yes, that would be really helpful if you can explain by a picture.

Comment: [This picture](https://sciencevspseudoscience.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/complex_plane.png) should say enough. [Source](https://galileospendulum.org/2013/04/08/talk-mathy-to-me-whats-the-square-root-of-i/).

Comment: @Shamtam You aren't getting the point, what I'm saying is that \$\frac{1}{\omega C}>0\$ and \$Z_{c} < 0\$. So why we represent \$Z_{C}\$ on positive imaginary axis?

Comment: @SahilSilare You dropped the negative. \$|Z_C| = \frac{1}{\omega C}\$, but \$Z_C = \frac{1}{j\omega C} = -\frac{j}{\omega C} = j(-\frac{1}{\omega C})\$

Comment: What you miss to understand is \$\frac{1}{ωC}\$ can only be positive. There are neither negative frequencies nor negative capacitances.